How to Implement a Model in NestJS Using TypeORM Entities with Method Access for Business Logic?
I'm working on a NestJS application, and I'm trying to implement a model that integrates with TypeORM entities to simplify business logic. I want to be able to call methods on entities retrieved from the repository, making it feel more object-oriented.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Defining the Entity
I've created a ProductEntity that extends a ProductModel class and implements a ProductInterface:
@Entity()
export class ProductEntity extends ProductModel implements ProductInterface {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  title: string;
}


Defining the Model
The ProductModel class contains a method getName:
export class ProductModel {
  getName() {
    return 'producto de showcase';
  }
}


Using the Model Methods
With this setup, I can retrieve entities from the repository and use the model's methods directly on the entity. Here’s an example of how I’m using it:
async test() {
  const products = await this.productRepo.find();
  return products[0].getName();
}



Goal and Benefits
My goal is to create a model where I can manage business logic directly on the entity itself. This approach feels more in line with object-oriented programming and makes it easier to handle associations and calls in a structured way.
Question

Is this a good approach in terms of best practices within NestJS and TypeORM?
Are there potential pitfalls or limitations with this design, especially as it scales?
Would you recommend an alternative way to structure models and entities in NestJS if I want to keep business logic and entity data closely associated?

The cons I have so far:

Violation of Domain and Persistence Separation
Potential Issues with TypeORM Lifecycle and Proxies
Scalability Concerns
How to test..

I’d appreciate any insights or recommendations! Thanks in advance! 
